# Converting a Java program that uses OpenCV (external jar) into an applet

Tags: java, html, opencv, jar, applet

I've been searching on this site and all over the internet on how to convert a java program that uses GUI into an applet. I've found general tutorials, like for basic programs, but mine uses OpenCV (http://opencv.org/) to generate the image, and then a JFrame makes it into a GUI. I've managed to put all the code into one class file, so that I could make modifications to it in order to make it run like an applet (such as getting rid of the "main" method and using public void init()), then there was the whole process of trying to put it into HTML code, where I tried just straight  tags, and also tried creating a jar file and using that with both  and deployJava.js (the java deployment script for applets). I have managed to get nothing to run off of a browser page. All I would need it to do is run as soon as the html page loads, at most from the click of a button (but only if necessary). From not-found exceptions to security exceptions to InvocationTargetException. So any help in how I can put this program online?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


public class BookOfFateProgram extends JFrame{



    public BookOfFateProgram(){


        //Creating the base image
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java246");
        Mat image = Mat.zeros(500, 500, CvType.CV_32F);
        Scalar white = new Scalar(255,255,255);
        Scalar blackColor = new Scalar(0,0,0);
        Point topLeftPoint = new Point(0,0);
        Point bottomRightPoint = new Point(500,500);
        Core.rectangle(image, topLeftPoint, bottomRightPoint, white, -1);



        //Generating the random table to create the pattern
        Mat table = new Mat(4,4,CvType.CV_32F);
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                table.put(i, j, Math.round(rand.nextDouble())+1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("table =" + table.dump());
        System.out.println();



        //Separating the table rows
        Mat m1 = table.row(0);
        Mat m2 = table.row(1);
        Mat m3 = table.row(2);
        Mat m4 = table.row(3);
        System.out.println("m1 =" + m1.dump());
        System.out.println("m2 =" + m2.dump());
        System.out.println("m3 =" + m3.dump());
        System.out.println("m4 =" + m4.dump());
        System.out.println();



        //Separating the table columns
        Mat d1 = table.col(0).t();
        Mat d2 = table.col(1).t();
        Mat d3 = table.col(2).t();
        Mat d4 = table.col(3).t();
        System.out.println("d1 =" + d1.dump());
        System.out.println("d2 =" + d2.dump());
        System.out.println("d3 =" + d3.dump());
        System.out.println("d4 =" + d4.dump());
        System.out.println();



        //Finding the XORs of the pairs of rows
        Mat n1 = m1.mul(m2);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = n1.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                n1.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                n1.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        Mat n2 = m3.mul(m4);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = n2.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                n2.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                n2.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("n1 =" + n1.dump());
        System.out.println("n2 =" + n2.dump());
        System.out.println();



        //Finding the XORs of the pairs of columns
        Mat e1 = d1.mul(d2);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = e1.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                e1.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                e1.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        Mat e2 = d3.mul(d4);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = e2.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                e2.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                e2.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("e1 =" + e1.dump());
        System.out.println("e2 =" + e2.dump());
        System.out.println();



        //Finding the XOR of the XORs of rows
        Mat x = n1.mul(n2);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = x.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                x.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                x.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("x =" + x.dump());



        //Finding XOR of the XORs of columns
        Mat y = e1.mul(e2);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = y.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                y.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                y.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("y =" + y.dump());
        System.out.println();



        //Finding the final XOR and pattern
        Mat z = x.mul(y);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            double[] a = z.get(0, i);
            if(a[0]==4 || a[0]==1){
                z.put(0, i, 2);
            }else{
                z.put(0, i, 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("z =" + z.dump());



        //All possible circles
        Point x1 = new Point(100,75);
        Point x2 = new Point(125,75);
        Point x3 = new Point(150,75);
        Point x4 = new Point(100,125);
        Point x5 = new Point(125,125);
        Point x6 = new Point(150,125);
        Point x7 = new Point(100,175);
        Point x8 = new Point(125,175);
        Point x9 = new Point(150,175);
        Point x10 = new Point(100,225);
        Point x11 = new Point(125,225);
        Point x12 = new Point(150,225);

        Point y1 = new Point(350,75);
        Point y2 = new Point(375,75);
        Point y3 = new Point(400,75);
        Point y4 = new Point(350,125);
        Point y5 = new Point(375,125);
        Point y6 = new Point(400,125);
        Point y7 = new Point(350,175);
        Point y8 = new Point(375,175);
        Point y9 = new Point(400,175);
        Point y10 = new Point(350,225);
        Point y11 = new Point(375,225);
        Point y12 = new Point(400,225);

        Point z1 = new Point(225,275);
        Point z2 = new Point(250,275);
        Point z3 = new Point(275,275);
        Point z4 = new Point(225,325);
        Point z5 = new Point(250,325);
        Point z6 = new Point(275,325);
        Point z7 = new Point(225,375);
        Point z8 = new Point(250,375);
        Point z9 = new Point(275,375);
        Point z10 = new Point(225,425);
        Point z11 = new Point(250,425);
        Point z12 = new Point(275,425);



        //Drawing the patterns
        double[] a = x.get(0, 0);
        if(a[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, x1, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, x3, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, x2, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        a = x.get(0, 1);
        if(a[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, x4, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, x6, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, x5, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        a = x.get(0, 2);
        if(a[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, x7, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, x9, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, x8, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        a = x.get(0, 3);
        if(a[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, x10, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, x12, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, x11, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }

        double[] b = y.get(0, 0);
        if(b[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, y1, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, y3, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, y2, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        b = y.get(0, 1);
        if(b[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, y4, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, y6, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, y5, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        b = y.get(0, 2);
        if(b[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, y7, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, y9, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, y8, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        b = y.get(0, 3);
        if(b[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, y10, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, y12, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, y11, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }

        double[] c = z.get(0, 0);
        if(c[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, z1, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, z3, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, z2, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        c = z.get(0, 1);
        if(c[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, z4, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, z6, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, z5, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        c = z.get(0, 2);
        if(c[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, z7, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, z9, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, z8, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }
        c = z.get(0, 3);
        if(c[0]==2){
            Core.circle(image, z10, 10, blackColor, -1);
            Core.circle(image, z12, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }else{
            Core.circle(image, z11, 10, blackColor, -1);
        }


        LoadImage("C:/Users/Sean P Meadows/Pictures/test.jpg", image);


    }



    public void LoadImage(String imgStr, Mat m){
        Highgui.imwrite(imgStr,m);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Book of Fate");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgStr);
        frame.setSize(image.getIconWidth()+10, image.getIconHeight()+35);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(" ", image, JLabel.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

        frame.validate();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        BookOfFateProgram b = new BookOfFateProgram();
    }

}









<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>The Book of Fate</title>

<link rel="icon" href="file:///C:/Users/Sean%20P%20Meadows/Documents/OPENCV_Project/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">

<style>



</style>

</head>


<body>

<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var dir = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var url = dir + "BookOfFate_webstart.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.7.0');
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Edit**
So I've made it all the way to the .jnlp file and the Deployment Toolkit script in the HTML file. I wasn't 100% sure how to properly format the pathnames in both files when asking for file locations. Everything is on my local machine. When I open the HTML in browser and select the button, it is unable to launch the application, exception being

This is the .jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Book Of Fate</title>
        <vendor>Sean Meadows</vendor>
        <icon href="file:///C:/Users/Sean%20P%20Meadows/Documents/OPENCV_Project/favicon.ico"/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="BookOfFateJWS.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc name="Book Of Fate" main-class="BookOfFateProgram" width="500" height="500">
    </application-desc>
    <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

and the html script call:

```
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var dir = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var url = dir + "BookOfFate_webstart.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.7.0');
</script>
```

Comment: *"..then a JFrame makes it into a GUI.."*  Deploy the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and you can side step the many problems inherent to embedding an applet.  Of course, the frame launched using JWS will still need to be digitally signed and requesting `all-permissions` like the applet, but it will still save a lot of headaches.

Comment: I am looking into the Java Web Start (I originally thought applet because I didn't want a user to have to download the app), but as a side question, would you know how to resolve:

AccessControlException
access denied("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.opencv_java246")

The loadLibrary method is what's used to access the OpenCV library used to set up the image. More info about the exception only gives:

CacheEntry[file:**pathname**/BookOfFate.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Fri Apr 18 15:39:19 EDT 2014,length=4458670

Comment: *"would you know how to resolve: AccessControlException.."*  What did the 2nd sentence of my first comment mean to you?

Comment: I was just checking, either in the case that if I ever wanted to attempt an applet again or the same exception comes up while making the JWS (still in the process), as it will still be calling the external library.

Comment: That comment does not answer my question to you.  BTW - Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: I thought it meant putting the application online in the form of a Java Web Start instead of an applet, such that instead of it creating a frame/window in the browser page, it would be a button or link that made an external pop-up window. I for the most part understand signing it with jarsigner.

Comment: It looks like I have the JWS setup complete, because when I run the .jnlp, I do not get any runtime exceptions. The only thing I do get is "Application Blocked by Security Settings". The java security slider is set to medium, and I've restarted my web browser so it could take effect, but it is still blocked. The manifest in my jar file has permissions set to all-permissions. Some tutorials suggested using a web server instead of local machine. Any advice on this?

Comment: *"Any advice on this?"*  None of that mentions the JNLP file.  Show the current file as an edit to the question.  Have you validated it using JaNeLA?

Comment: The edited JNLP file is up, as is the HTML file it goes with. I am unsure how to use JaNeLA to validate it.

Comment: The JNLP also needs to declare `all-permissions` in a `security` element.

Comment: We are making some progress. The <security> element is added, between <information> and <resources>. It went so far as a Security Warning asking if I wanted to run the app, but then said it was unable to launch because of a ClassNotFoundException; it couldn't find the BookOfFateProgram main-class file, even though it is in the root of the .jar file.

Comment: `BookOfFateProgram` has no `package` declaration?

Comment: It is in a project named "BookOfFate" in eclipse, so I think that would technically be the package declaration. The file is in BookOfFate\bin\BookOfFateProgram.class. Should I create the .jar file so that it is located in those folders instead of being at the root of the .jar? The .jar was created in the same directory as BookOfFateProgram.class, so that is why it is at the root.

Comment: *"It is in a project named "BookOfFate" in eclipse, so I think that would technically be the package declaration"* ?!?  The package declaration should be the first line of the source file (it needs to be before imports).  Look in the source file, is there a line starting `package` at the top of the source?  And I must point out, that you seem to be a newbie at all this.  Deployment is an advanced topic.  A lot harder (to do right, for an average end user) than developers expect.

Comment: BTW - just noticed you'd posted the source code.  If that is the ***entire*** source, the code has no package.  Why is it still a `JApplet`?

Comment: I forgot to edit the source code here out of applet style, I only did it on my machine. That part is fixed. The program itself runs fine in eclipse without the package declaration; it generates the correct output. I have experience with Java and HTML and a few other web components separately, but this is the first time I've brought it together in order to publicly deploy something. I put all the code into one source file for my own sake.

Comment: ..Do you have experience with answering questions?  I asked you one, and still don't see the answer.

Comment: I apologize, the code is no longer a JApplet.

Comment: *"is there a line starting package at the top of the source?"*  And by that I mean the 'new' source.  The source that only you have (not very handy, that).

Comment: There is no line in my code declaring the package.

Comment: Eclipse puts project code into a (default package).

Comment: Did JaNeLA make no error or warning from the empty `href`?  I can't quite recall how it handled that, but put the correct URL in.

Comment: I mentioned earlier I was unsure how to use JaNeLa, so I haven't received any error or warning. [Deploying a Java Web Start Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html) The NOTE in step 5 states [tag:href] is optional in JWS that run Java SE 6 update 18 or later, so I omitted it.

Comment: Which part of *"Open JNLP descriptor from [File]|[URL]"* do you not understand?  I'm about to give up trying to help you, since getting useful information or action from you is about as pleasant as pulling teeth.  Ultimately, it is your problem, so why should *I* bother giving you *more* patience than I think I have remaining?

Comment: I apologize for causing you problems. You said nothing about a JNLP descriptor. You did say deployment was an advanced topic, and I agree. That's why I came here for help. I have answered your questions, and have been going through all the actions on my end, which is hard to show here. Most everything you've said so far has helped. The janela.jar you offered earlier came with no instructions or descriptor, hence my confusion. Again I'm sorry, you have been helping.

Comment: So I listened to what you said and created a separate package (not the default one eclipse makes) with the program in it, modified the JNLP, moved some files around on my machine, and now it works. It creates the popup window that it should. Thanks for your help.